# Как запустить .exe на AppVeyor?

Tags: c++, c, github, непрерывная-интеграция, appveyor

Скомпилировал g++ => получился `exe`. Я могу его как-то запустить в консоли AppVeyor?

Если просто в `appveyor.yml` написать `cmd: some.exe`, то выходят с огромадным кодом ошибки.

Это exe Google-теста, и чтобы получить результат теста, нужно его запустить.
Не получается.

[**Мой appveyor.yml**](https://github.com/Kristinita/g_test_sum/blob/master/appveyor.yml):

```
version: 1.0.{build}

os: Visual Studio 2015

clone_script:
  - cmd: git clone -q --recursive --branch=%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH% https://github.com/%APPVEYOR_REPO_NAME%.git %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%
  - cmd: git checkout -qf %APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT%

install:
  - set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin; #C:\projects\g-test-sum\external\googletest\googletest\include;
  - copy c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe c:\MinGW\bin\make.exe
  - cmd: set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan

build_script: 
  - make 
test_script:
  - cmd: C:\projects\g-test-sum\summator_unittest.exe
```

[**Результаты сборки**](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Kristinita/g-test-sum):

```
Build started
git clone -q --recursive --branch=%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH% https://github.com/%APPVEYOR_REPO_NAME%.git %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%
Submodule 'external/googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'external/googletest'
Cloning into 'external/googletest'...
Submodule path 'external/googletest': checked out 'a2b8a8e07628e5fd60644b6dd99c1b5e7d7f1f47'
git checkout -qf %APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT%
Running Install scripts
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin;
copy c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe c:\MinGW\bin\make.exe
        1 file(s) copied.
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Conan\conan
make
Building on Windows/MinGW
g++  -c src/summator.cpp -o test/summator.o
g++ -Iexternal/googletest/googletest/include -I../ -g -Wall -Wextra  -c test/summator_unittest.cpp -o test/summator_unittest.o
g++ -Iexternal/googletest/googletest/include -I../ -Iexternal/googletest/googletest -g -Wall -Wextra  -c \
external/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc -lpthread -DWINVER=0x0500 -o test/gtest-all.o
g++ -Iexternal/googletest/googletest/include -I../ -Iexternal/googletest/googletest -g -Wall -Wextra  -c \
    external/googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc -lpthread -o test/gtest_main.o
ar rv test/gtest_main.a test/gtest-all.o test/gtest_main.o
a - test/gtest-all.o
a - test/gtest_main.o
ar: creating test/gtest_main.a
g++ -Iexternal/googletest/googletest/include -I../ -g -Wall -Wextra  test/summator.o test/summator_unittest.o test/gtest_main.a -DWINVER=0x0500 -o summator_unittest
dir 
Makefile  appveyor.yml  external  src  summator_unittest.exe  test
C:\projects\g-test-sum\summator_unittest.exe
Command exited with code -1073741511
```

Или, как переделать мой `appveyor.yml` так, чтобы `exe` запускались?
ЗЫ: другие экзешники типа "хэлло ворлд" запускаются.
Спасибо.

Comment: я думаю что приложение просит точку входа, а это `int main` как-бы

Answer (score 0):

Перво-наперво необходимо перевести код возврата в шестнадцатеричный вид, используемый всей MSDN-вской документацией.

-1073741511<sub>10</sub> = C0000139<sub>16</sub>.

В Windows этот номер закреплён за ошибкой `STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND`. Смотрим [описание](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) этой ошибки:

> **0xC0000139 STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND**
>
> {Точка входа не найдена} Точка входа в процедуру `%hs` не была обнаружена в динамической библиотеке.

Стоит пояснить, что под «точками входа» документация имеет в виду экспортируемые функции.

То есть операционная система хочет нам сказать, что все нужные для запуска библиотеки были найдены и загружены, но в одной из них не оказалось требуемой функции.